# Prevent Focus onCreate Activity

Tags: java, android, focus, android-textinputlayout

I need remove or prevent focus when activity start and i have used some code like:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

But always on start the focus go in first **TextInputLayout** without keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`** in manifest file

And  Use in your Root **`ConstraintLayout`** Layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add -

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

In your xml file above the EditText and it will do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Add these lines

android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

to the parent layout in xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
```